# Is the graph transformation vertices to edges efficiently computable?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is this graph transformation G_1 to G_2 efficiently computable?

1. All vertices in G_1 are unique edges in G_2
2. Adjacent vertices in G_1 are adjacent edges in G_2

The inverse transformation (edges to vertices) is trivial.

I can encode it as CSP, but I am not sure solving is tractable:

adjacent V1,V2 in G_1 to (V1',V1''), (V2',V2'') in G_2, must share a vertex, constraints: V1'=V2' / V1'=V2'' / V1''=V2' / V1''=V2'' and some disequations.

References, search terms will be apreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible if $G_1$ is the [line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of $G_2$. Not all graphs are line graphs.

> A graph $G$ is the line graph of some other graph, if and only if it is possible to find a collection of cliques in $G$, partitioning the edges of $G$, such that each vertex of $G$ belongs to at most two of the cliques.

[Here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V0F-45FCW4T-37&_user=10&_coverDate=10%2F31%2F1973&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=bde3a2a5cadbc74f8878ccdfc7ac7989&searchtype=a) you can find am algorithm to recover the original graph from it's line graph.

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.